# How to make a multicriteria search with offset and limit in jpa repository in spring boot?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've got an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Attempt {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private LocalDateTime attemptTime;
    private long processingTimeNanos;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double r;
    private boolean result;

    public Attempt() {
    }

    public Attempt(double x, double y, double r, boolean result) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(double r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public boolean isResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(boolean result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getAttemptTime() {
        return attemptTime;
    }

    public void setAttemptTime(LocalDateTime attemptTime) {
        this.attemptTime = attemptTime;
    }

    public long getProcessingTimeNanos() {
        return processingTimeNanos;
    }

    public void setProcessingTimeNanos(long processingTime) {
        this.processingTimeNanos = processingTime;
    }


}
```

And I want to implement a solution to be able to make a method based on query with search by any number of any fields and also use offset and limit for the rows in my jpa repository. How can I do it?
I tried to make

```
@Repository
public interface AttemptsRepository extends JpaRepository<Attempt, Integer> {
    /**
     * Makes a search in the database by the given parameters with the given offset and size
     * @param offset
     * @param size
     * @param id
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param r
     * @param result
     * @param time
     * @param processingTime
     * @return
     */
    @Query("""
        select A from Attempt A
        where (?3 is null or A.id like %?1%)
        and (?4 is null or A.x like %?4%)
        and (?5 is null or A.y like %?5%)
        and (?6 is null or A.r like %?6%)
        and (?7 is null or A.result like %?7%)
        and (?8 is null or A.attemptTime like %?8%)
        and (?9 is null or A.processingTimeNanos like %?9%)
        order by A.id offset ?1 rows fetch next ?2 rows only
        """)
        List<Attempt> getPartAttempts(int offset, int size, String id, String x, String y, String r, String result, String time, String processingTime);
}
```

But I got an exception:
[image]

How can I implement the method for this kind of query?
Update: I use mysql as db

Comment: Have you looked whether the database you are using actually supports `offset`? That is likely your problem. The db not supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

I missed `nativeQuery = true` parameter in the annotation. That's why there was an error